# Removing left padding zero in SSIS

Tags: ssis

How to remove left padding zero in column values.The data type of column is Unicode string[DT_WSTR].
Please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Cast it to DT_I4 then back to DT_WSTR, that should get rid of the leading zeros.

Comment: if this solved your problem, you should mark it as the accepted by clicking the check-mark to the left.

Answer (score 1):

```
Replace(Ltrim(Replace(column1, '0', ' ')), ' ', '0')
```

This will remove your leading zero, but make sure you string doesn't have any white spaces,this code will not work for such case