# SSIS remove Left zero from csv Flat File Source

Tags: ssis

I have a csv file that I want to process in SSIS. The file contains a column type string Unicode string [DT_WSTR], example: ColumnA -> (`"00000123400"`).

I want to delete the zeroes that are on the left of 123400 and also delete the quotes and have a result as following: `123400`.

For quotation marks I find the following solution via Derived Column: `REPLACE (ColumnA, "\" "," ")`, which gives me the following result: `00000123400`.

How to remove the zeroes which are on the left?

After deleting the quotation marks, I tried to convert my string to integer [DT_I4], but that does not remove the zeroes.

Do you have the answer to my case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of a part of the case is:

in our Derived column put the expression:

```
REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(ColumnA,"0","")),"","0")
```

It remove just left zero

you can see the link: [Removing left padding zero in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378385/removing-left-padding-zero-in-ssis)

It work perfectly, but is it possible to trim left zero, and also delete quotation marks in the same time in expression?

Example: I have Column1 which is string with quotation marks and left zero - "0000123400"

I try this expression:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(column1, "0", " ")), " ", "0"),"\""," ")
```

but it doesn't work, it deletes all zeros and returns 1234.

The solution that I want is to get 123400.

Should I do it one by one? Create a delivered column and delete quotation marks first, and after create an other delivered column for Left zero ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the output to be in numeric form?  If so, the following expression will remove the quotes and leading zeros while preserving the trailing zeros from Unicode text.  This can be done in a single operation, with one Derived Column that will create a new column (*add a new column* option) with an integer output data type in the data flow.

```
(DT_I4)REPLACE(ColumnA,"\"","")
```

If you want to keep this as the Unicode data type the expression below will do this, also in a single Derived Column.  Just adjust the length according to your columns.

```
(DT_WSTR, 50)(DT_I4)REPLACE(CoulmnA,"\"","")
```

Comment: Thanks you for answering, i Will try that , thanks a lot